# to rewrite url in Global.asax, ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-1.1, global-asax, url-mapping

HEllo. I need replace double slashes in one slash. I am planning do this in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest event. Is it enough? or better do a http module?
Thank you.

---

**UPD**

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' Fires at the beginning of each request 
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo(AppSettings.UsedCulture)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture


         Dim retUrl As String
         ....
         some code 
         ....

        'Dim app As HttpApplication = CType(sender, HttpApplication)
        'app.Context.RewritePath(retUrl)

         Dim myContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
        'Rewrite the internal path            
         myContext.RewritePath(retUrl)

    End If
```

I am using .Net 1.1. And It must be on .Net 1.1
RewritePath does not rewrite URL.Why?

**UPD2**
Having decided to make addition redirect in Sub Application_BeginRequest with new rewritting url.

Comment: There is great article from scottgu blog about URL rewriting, hope it helps: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS 7.0 (and newer), you can use the [IIS UrlRewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite). We've been using it for a while, and have no complaints.

Comment: we are using IIS 6.0, Thank you for the link.